# How to check that the response content is in gzip, zip, xml etc format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gzip, ebay-api

I am calling an eBay downloadfile which return this headers:

```
{
  :server => "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  :x_ebay_soa_service_metrics => "39085693",
  :x_ebay_soa_request_id => "15e7abe4-6a10-a9cb-1704-67b4ffb0d86d!FileTransferService!10.156.177.112!v3apibulkcore[]",
  :x_ebay_soa_service_version => "1.1.0",
  :x_ebay_soa_message_protocol => "NONE",
  :x_ebay_soa_response_data_format => "XML",
  :x_ebay_soa_operation_name => "downloadFile",
  :x_ebay_soa_service_name => "{http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services}FileTransferService",
  :content_encoding => "gzip",
  :content_type => "multipart/related;boundary=MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_11F13BE1DC196154D715052978439058176159;type=\"application/xop+xml\";start=\"<0.urn:uuid:11F13BE1DC196154D715052978439058176160>\";start-info=\"text/xml\"",
  :transfer_encoding => "chunked",
  :date => "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:17:23 GMT"
}
```

In this headers response, it shows that  **:content_encoding=>"gzip"**, but the following line returns error `Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format`:

> {  Base64.decode64(response),     input = StringIO.new(raw),
>   Zlib::GzipReader.new(input).read }

Comment: What code did you use to get  `:content_encoding` from response?

Comment: response.headers[:content_encoding]